# How to fix Error: [PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a protected route for the admin dashboard. Sign-in and Sign-up routes are public. Before creating a protected route every route was working well. I created a component to create a private route. I replaced the route as a Private route and the page loads and terminal gives no error. But the page renders nothing and the console throws an error as the private route is not a route component. All children of routes must be a route or react. fragment.

**Privet Route Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    return <Route {...props} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter , Routes ,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './container/Home/Home'
import Signin from './container/Signin/Signin'
import Signup from './container/Signup/Signup'
import PrivateRoute from './components/HOC/privateRoute'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <PrivateRoute path='/' exact element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin/>}/>
          <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup/>}/>
          <Route/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Related, assuming Router6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69923420/how-to-use-private-route-in-react-router-domv6

Comment: index.tsx:19 Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>. @isherwood

Comment: that link in the first comment above has the answer to your question. In v6 you can't use `PrivateRoute` the way you are attempting to do, you need a wrapper. Just read the answers to the link above